# Fitting a simple power law function in R

Tags: r, regression, power-law

I want to use a power function on the classic surface area to volume relationship.

```
surfaceArea<-c(6,24,54)
volume<-c(1,8,27)
```

Logging the data works to get the parameter values of the linear function as follows

```
logSurfaceArea<-log10(surfaceArea)
logVolume<-log10(volume)

plot(logSurfaceArea~logVolume, pch =16)
allometryModel <-lm(logSurfaceArea~logVolume)
summary(allometryModel)
```

But how do I get the parameter values for the original power function?

Comment: You start from a model in which `S = k * V^alpha`, then take the `log` and you get `logS = log k + alpha*log V`. This is the linear model you evaluated in the `allometryModel` object. As you can see the intercept is `log k` so `k = exp(intercept)`. The `alpha` coefficient is the `logVolume` coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use mathematical way of thinking. Let's say **y** is surfaceArea and **x** is volume, then what you are fitting with the **lm** function is this:

log10(y) = a*log10(x) + b,

then

y = 10^(a * log10(x) + b) = 10^(a * log10(x)) * 10^b = (10^(log10(x)))^a * 10^b = x^a * 10^b

you can check it plotting these plots:

```
 plot(volume, volume^allometryModel$coeff[2]*10.0^allometryModel$coeff[1], col="red")
 plot(volume, surfaceArea)
```

Please note, that you need to propagate properly the errors if you would like to use the coefficient errors provided by the **lm** function.

Comment: So it's quite a roundabout way to get the power law function plotted. Could I set it up so that I could extract the coefficients from that model?